# Port Forwarding to changing internal IP address

Tags: networking, router, ip, port-forwarding, ip-camera

I have a security IP cam that I like to check remotely. I have set up my router to forward to the port I have assigned to the cam, etc. Here is the problem. My ISP router periodically changes the local IP assignment to the cam and then the forwarding fails because it is only set up to work with a single local IP address. This often happens when there is a temporary drop in connectivity, which is happening somewhat frequently lately. Is there a way to forward to more than one local IP address in case the assignment changes? Or is there some other way to ensure uninterrupted remote access to the camera?

Answer (score 4):

If it's the internal (LAN) IP changing (which should be outside of the ISPs control), then set the camera up to have a [static IP instead of using a dynamic one handled by DHCP](http://whatismyipaddress.com/dynamic-static).

If it's your WAN (public) address that's changing, sign up for a [Dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) (DDNS) service like [No-ip](http://www.noip.com/), or [DynDNs](http://dyn.com/dns/) or alike, and start using the host/domain name they provide you instead of your public IP address.